# AWS Load Balancer is unable to parse my certificate, the PEM format is requested. How do I convert my certificate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, ssl-certificate, load-balancing, aws-cli

When trying to add `https` listener to the AWS load balancer as instructed in [this guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-update-ssl-cert.html#us-update-lb-SSLcert-console), using AWS console, I get the following error:

> Unable to parse certificate. Please ensure the certificate is in PEM
> format aws console

I gave the the corresponding certificate as text (same as in the guide). But the above error comes saying that its not in the PEM format.

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIj.....IDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

and

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIE....68J
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong here?

You are using a key that is in the wrong format -  RSA. You will need to [convert your RSA format file to a PEM format](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26924/how-do-i-convert-a-ssh-keygen-public-key-into-a-format-that-openssl-pem-read-bio).